# Can you have duplicate dojo-data-attach-points in the same template?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've created a templated widget, and there are two places in the template that I'd like to update with the same value at runtime. Something similar to:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
  Site: <span data-dojo-attach-point="siteNameNode">Placeholder</span>
</div>

...

<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">
  Site: <span data-dojo-attach-point="siteNameNode">Placeholder</span>
</div>
```

In my Javascript I have:

```
_setSiteNameAttr: { node: "siteNameNode", type: "innerHTML" },
...
this.set("siteName", "Your Site Name");
```

When the code runs only the second siteNameNode is updated. Does this mean the attach points must be unique in a template, or is there a different way to work with duplicates? If duplicates are not allowed, is there a common way to update multiple values at once, or do I need to give the nodes different attach point names?

Thanks. I'm using Dojo 1.8.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach points are a reference to a DOM node. If you try to connect two DOM nodes to the same attach point, I don't think that would work out since you have two different DOM nodes (that's why only the last is being stored as the attach point).

But why don't you just set the content of the nodes to the same value like in the example below? Just rename your second attach point to `siteNameNode2` and you're set.

```
html.set(this.siteNameNode, "Your Site Name");
html.set(this.siteNameNode2, "Your Site Name");
```

I'm using the `dojo/html` module to set the inner HTML of both DOM nodes to the same content, but you can also do something like:

```
this.siteNameNode.innerHTML = "Your Site Name";
```

The DOM nodes of your attach point are stored as a property with the same name in your widget, so it's easy to access/modify.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and suggestion, Dimitri.